# elastic4s query document with list of keys

Tags: elastic4s

I'm trying to retrieve records from elastic search repo. And my method looks like this

```
def findPartialFieldWithId(id: String, path: String): Future[SearchResponse] = {
client.execute {
    search in IndexType query {
    termQuery("_id", id)
    } sourceInclude (path)
}
```

}

But if `id` is a list of String instead of String, what DSL should i use?

tried to read elastic4s docs and test cases, but still can't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`termsQuery` is the way to go:

```
def findPartialFieldWithId(ids: Seq[String], path: String): Future[SearchResponse] = {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  client.execute {
    search in IndexType query {
      termsQuery("_id", ids: _* )
    } sourceInclude (path)
  }
}
```